# ionic get file name from file-chooser or file-picker

Tags: ionic3

As per title, currently both file-chooser and file-picker only returns URI like following:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/7621
```

how do I actually get the file name of the chosen file?

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, I can get the file name on Android using this library https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/

Still finding a way for iOS though

Answer (score 0):

filePath will help you resolve the path, here is how :

install the plugin like this :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath
npm install @ionic-native/file-path
```

Then import it in your app-module

```
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
```

and add it as a provider

```
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,

{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },

FilePath

],
```

Then import it in your page component

```
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
```

and add it as a constructor parameter on the page

```
constructor(private filePath: FilePath) { }
```

the use it in on your page like so

```
selectFile()
{
    this.fileChooser.open()
    .then(uri => 
    {

      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
                  .then(filePath => {
                     console.log(filePath)
                   // now do what you want with the filePath
                  })


    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

meanwhile I assumed you already have fileChooser installed.

Hope this helps someone.